# optaplanner Run Examples in IDE, NetBeans maven plugin is missing

Tags: maven, netbeans, optaplanner

I´m trying to optimizes a planning problem with OptaPlanner - it should be a lightweight and easy.
It´s the first time I get in contact with such programming stuff, but I´m quite proud for going as fare in a few days (for it is not easy at all - and all in English (I´m German) - Last time I was programming Pascal 25 years ago in secondary-school.)

I downloaded and installed

- optaplanner-distribution-6.5.0.Final.zip
- jre-8u121-windows-x64.exe

I could run the Examples!

Now I would like to customise one example and therefore run the Examples in an IDE fist.
I downloaded and installed

- NetBeans 8.2 Patch 1
- jdk-8u121-nb-8_2-windows-x64.exe
- apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip

So I just open the file examples/sources/pom.xml as a new project (as  recommended in OptaPlanner User Guide 1.4.2)
but the maven integration will not take care of the rest.

I receive the error report below.

What should I do now?
Is there a simple trick I could use?
Or a simpler way to succeed?

Or is this all to difficult for the fist task?
Do I have to learn all about maven plugins?
Do I have to be an NetBeans expert fist?

> Downloaded: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom/2.0.0-alpha-8/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom-2.0.0-alpha-8.pom (6 KB at 7.1 KB/sec)
>
> Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.optaplanner:optaplanner-examples:jar:7.0.0.Beta7
>   'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin is missing. @ org.kie:kie-parent:7.0.0.Beta7, C:\Users\ray-club.m2\repository\org\kie\kie-parent\7.0.0.Beta7\kie-parent-7.0.0.Beta7.pom, line 1173, column 15
>   'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jxr-plugin is missing. @ org.kie:kie-parent:7.0.0.Beta7, C:\Users\ray-club.m2\repository\org\kie\kie-parent\7.0.0.Beta7\kie-parent-7.0.0.Beta7.pom, line 1177, column 15
>   'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.kie:kie-parent:7.0.0.Beta7, C:\Users\ray-club.m2\repository\org\kie\kie-parent\7.0.0.Beta7\kie-parent-7.0.0.Beta7.pom, line 1203, column 15
>
> It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
>
> For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.

and at the end

> Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message: To build this project Maven 3.2.5 (or greater) is required. Please install it.
>
> BUILD FAILURE
>   Total time: 4:00.537s
>   Finished at: Sat Mar 25 17:21:31 CET 2017
>   Final Memory: 22M/154M
>
> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven-version) on project optaplanner-examples: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: "Maven 3.2.5 (or greater) is required" with `apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip` that should work, so I think you have 2 maven installations (and old one and that new one). Try "mvn --version" on the command line.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\ray-club>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:4
7+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

C:\Users\ray-club>

Comment: NetBeans  is delivered with Maven in a bundle.
NetBeans is using a different version of maven.
I changed it in NetBeans from the main window I hav chosen Tools/Options/Java/Maven/Execution/Maven Home

Building the pom.xml I get a lot of error reports now:

BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 18:45 min
Finished at: 2017-03-27T10:03:51+02:00
Final Memory: 49M/265M
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) on project optaplanner-examples: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
/D:/Architektur und Projekte/Ableger/Simone/optaplanner/optaplanner-distribution-6.5.0.Final/examples/sources/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/tsp/domain/TravelingSalesmanTour.java:[36,54] package org.optaplanner.persistence.xstream.impl.score does not exist ....

Comment: ....symbol:   class LongConstraintMatchTotal
location: class org.optaplanner.examples.cheaptime.solver.score.CheapTimeIncrementalScoreCalculator
/D:/Architektur und Projekte/Ableger/Simone/optaplanner/optaplanner-distribution-6.5.0.Final/examples/sources/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/cheaptime/solver/score/CheapTimeIncrementalScoreCalculator.java:[537,9] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class LongConstraintMatchTotal
location: class org.optaplanner.examples.cheaptime.solver.score.CheapTimeIncrementalScoreCalculator
-> [Help 1]

Comment: Refresh netbeans maven configuration. Looks like the classpath isn't set correclty.

Or better yet, just do `cd optaplanner-examples; mvn exec:exec`

Comment: I did mvn exec:exec: ..... Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-exec
/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar (54 KB at 30.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] Total time: 10:46 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-28T09:31:23+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/145M
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (d
efault-cli) on project optaplanner-examples: The parameters 'executable' for goa
l org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec are missing or invalid -> [Help

Comment: 6.5.0.Final\examples\sources>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T18:29:2
3+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
D:\Architektur und Projekte\Ableger\Simone\optaplanner\optaplanner-distribution-
6.5.0.Final\examples\sources>

Comment: Oh sorry, that's `mvn exec:java` instead, see https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#getTheReleaseZipAndRunTheExamples